# How to allow Special Character '&' in java

Tags: java, character

I have the following code to allow the special character :

```
public static String replacer1(StringBuffer outBuffer) {

        String data = "";
        StringBuffer tempBuffer = null;
        try {
            if (outBuffer != null) {
                data = outBuffer.toString();
                tempBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                int incrementor = 0;
                int dataLength = data.length();
                while (incrementor < dataLength) {
                    char charecterAt = data.charAt(incrementor);
                    if (charecterAt == '%') {
                        tempBuffer.append("<percentage>");
                    } else if (charecterAt == '+') {
                        tempBuffer.append("<plus>");
                    }else if (charecterAt == '-') {
                        tempBuffer.append("<hyphen>");
                    } else if (charecterAt == '&') {
                        tempBuffer.append("<AMPERSAND>");
                    }  else if (charecterAt == '_') {
                        tempBuffer.append("<UNDERSCORE>");
                    }

                    else {
                        tempBuffer.append(charecterAt);
                    }
                    incrementor++;
                }
                data = tempBuffer.toString();
                data = URLDecoder.decode(data, "utf-8");
                data = data.replaceAll("<percentage>", "%");
                data = data.replaceAll("<plus>", "+");
                data = data.replaceAll("<hyphen>", "-");
                data = data.replaceAll("<AMPERSAND>", "&");
                data = data.replaceAll("<UNDERSCORE>", "_");
                //data = data.replaceAll("\"", "");
                data = data.replaceAll("'", "");
                data = data.trim();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

all the special charcters are comming except '&'.

IS there any other way?
Please help

Comment: @Sanjeev Why? I thought in a Java character literal, the only characters you had to escape were \ and '

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson you are right. i misunderstood the question.

Comment: @OP Can you clarify a bit - if you put a print statement just after that while loop, did your ampersands get correctly converted to the "<AMPERSAND>" string?

Comment: [ampersand works by itself](http://ideone.com/mO70Pl)